# Categories not visible in home page

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento. I added a new Category from the admin panel,set 'Include in navigation menu' to yes. Added new products to the Category, added product to the category by going to Products edit page, set the quantity in stock to some number greater than 0, set stock availability as 'in stock', refreshed the cache and re-indexed data but in vain, could not see the new category. However, when I register and login I could see the new category visible. I want the new category to be visible without any user registration/login.

Answer (score 0):

If this is new installation then there is nothing like this in magento. But if this is running website then please check the code.

Comment: Hi Santosh, Well its an already existing application (I did not install) Is it because of some customized theme being used in the front end?

Comment: In category edit options please check the visibility options (actually what you have set for this category)

Comment: Have set 'Include in Navigation Menu' to yes. In Display settings section Display Mode is set to Static block and products, CMS block (haven't chosen ). 'Is Anchor' is set to No